# Trying to access a String from another class?

Tags: java, bluej

I am having trouble accessing the `String` description from my `Picture` class in order to use it in the `PhotoViewer` class. I created a getter method, so I don't understand why I am getting the error

> cannot find symbol - method getDescription().

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Picture here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Picture extends Attachment
{
    protected String description;
    protected String height;
    protected String width;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Picture
     */
    public Picture(String filename, long size, String description, String height, String width)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.size = size;
        this.description = description;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    /**
     * Prints out the details of a picture attachment.
     */
    public void preview()
    {
        System.out.println("Filename: " + filename);
        System.out.println("Size: " + size);
        System.out.println("Description: " + description);
        System.out.println("Height: " + height);
        System.out.println("Width: " + width);
    }

    /**
     * Getter method that returns the description
     */
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

```
/**
 * Application to open and view photos
 * 
 * @author Chandler Warren 
 * @version 12-1-15
 */
public class PhotoViewer extends Application
{
    Picture picture;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class PhotoViewer
     */
    public PhotoViewer()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Abstract method to open the attachment
     */
    public void open(Attachment picture)
    {
        System.out.println("I am the PhotoViewer. You are viewing a picture of " + getDescription());
    }
}
```

[New error encountered when trying to initiate picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0tiA.png)

Comment: Should that be `picture.getDescription()`?

Comment: And the method parameter should be Picture, not Attachment. What is this Attachment class anyway?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually, it is supposed to be Attachment. I checked that with my teacher. I will add the Attachment class if that is helpful.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It appears Picture extends Attachment. So yes picture.getDescription() if it is declared in the attachment class

Comment: Then hopefully Attachment has a `getDescription()` method as well.

Comment: Also you might get confused when referencing the instance property `picture` and the function argument `picture`

Comment: picture is defined in the Picture class, but my teacher said I should use the Attachment class for the type for the method.

Comment: Did you initiate the picture instance......?

Comment: How do I do that? private Attachment picture?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution. I used casting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public void open(Attachment picture)
{
    System.out.println("I am the PhotoViewer. You are viewing a picture of " + picture.getDescription());
}
```

Will work assuming `picture` is properly instatiated (it isn't clear if you want to use the instance variable or the method variable, this example calls the method variable, but `this.picture` would call the instance variable). `getDescription()` is an instance method and therefore must be called from an object.

Comment: `this` is implicitly an Object, problem is `this` does not implement the method `getDescription()`

Comment: @WalterM the reason for my statement about `this` is that OP may by trying to access the method on the instance variable `picture` rather than the parameter for the method `picture`. I never call `this.getDescription()` so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: How would I go about properly instatiating it?

Comment: if you wanted to use the picture that you declared in the class by `Picture picture;` you would need to add `picture = new Picture(...)` in your constructor, and access the method with `this.picture.getDescription();`.

Comment: This would be in the PhotoViewer constructor?

Comment: @Chandler Warren yes if that's the way you want to do it

Comment: @KevinKlute I am getting a problem with the constructor, though. It takes 5 parameters that this class says it cannot find.

Comment: @ChandlerWarren Where are the parameters for your picture stored? Are they being grabbed from another class?

Comment: They are stored in Picture but also Attachment since Picture extends Attachment. Please see my edit above to see error.

Comment: @ChandlerWarren You have not created a filename variable. You will need to create it, or pass in a String. E.g. `String filename = "myFilename.jpg"`, or `Picture picture = new Picture("myFilename.jpg", 28, "Description goes here", 10, 10);`, replacing those values with the ones you want to use.

Comment: @ChandlerWarren What are you trying to do in the constructor that's not working? It says like as Fodder suggested you may not be creating the variables.